# AWS SNS Sending too many notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache2, amazon-sns

## Problem

#### In one sentence

SNS Topic sending too many notifications to HTTPs subscriber.

#### More detailed

I have enabled events in one of my S3 buckets, and I have subscribed one of my applications to its `SNS Topic` via `HTTPS`. Everything was working fine until today, when my app started taking too long to respond.

After restarting the EC2 instance and noticing that the problem was still there, I SSH'd to the EC2 instance and realized that I was connected almost instantly, commands were being executed with no noticeable delays. So I knew the problem was not with the instance network.

I went to check the apache logs and that's when I noticed hundreds (perhaps thousands) of POST requests per second. See a snippet of the logs below.

## Question(s)

- Is there a way to see whether it is S3 that is sending all these notifications events to SNS?
- Also, could this be that S3 is receiving that many uploads per second, is that even possible?
- Lastly, what can I do to stop this other than simply unsubscribing from the topic?

Apache logs:

```
72.21.217.87 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.133 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 6404 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.141 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.139 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.75 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:51 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.182 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.137 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.157 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.161 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.139 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.156 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 6404 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.70 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.135 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.152 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.113 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.83 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.158 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.129 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.75 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.156 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.64 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.134 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.130 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.86 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.167 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.135 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.169 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.76 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.75 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 6404 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.79 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.180 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.75 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.80 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.74 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 6404 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.137 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.155 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.87 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.152 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.130 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.161 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
72.21.217.74 - - [02/Mar/2017:15:33:52 -0500] "POST /notifications HTTP/1.1" 500 619 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
```

#### [Update]

After looking closer at the logs, I see that my app is responding with `500`. At first I thought it was Apache2 since it was receiving so many requests. I guess SNS continues to re-deliver messages (indefinitely?) when it doesn't receive a success message.

#### [Update 2]

I was able to get what notification was being sent, and it's a "ObjectRemoved:Delete" for a file that was deleted. The file no longer exists in the bucket.

I subscribed via email as suggested by @EEAA for less than 15 seconds, and have received 252 emails and counting :[ for the same notification.

#### [Update 3]

Checked the delivery policy on the SNS Topic, and confirmed that retries is set to 3!

[image]

Note: As of now, I've received almost 900 notifications from S3. I've also noticed that the `x-amz-request-id` and `x-amz-id-2` is always different, does this mean something?

Comment: Some are probably retries, given the 500s. I'd check your S3, though - maybe someone's got an API key and is popping lots of files there on your dime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was able to view what the notification that SNS is sending, and it was a file that I deleted. So I don't think these notifications are by someone else actions.

Comment: *does this mean something?*  Check your bucket logs.  It *should* mean that these aren't entirely duplicates.  I don't know if lifecycle policies trigger events, but that seems like one possibility.

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

1. Those IPs are all assigned to Amazon, so we know the traffic is coming from Amazon's network.
2. Your server is responding with a 500 error code. Is that intentional?
3. You should be able to do a packet capture to see the `POST` data.
4. If you're unable to perform a packet capture, you can also subscribe to the SNS topic via email for a *very* short period and details of the SNS message will be sent to your email.

Comment: I subscribed via email as you suggested, but I left it for too long (~15 seconds), I'm still getting emails 1200 emails later.

Comment: Haha, RIP your inbox. :) Were you able to get the information you needed though?

Comment: Lol - and they are still coming in at a slower rate, about 10 emails a minute (perhaps Gmail throttles it). I was able to notice that although the notifications are about the same file/object, the ids in the notifications are different, which implies that they are not retries but new messages.